# Wait for an array to be built by sibling in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a `Parent` component:

```
function Parent() {
  let lst = [];
  let refs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    lst.push(i);
  return <><Child1 lst={lst} refs={refs} /> <Child2 refs={refs} /> </>;
}
```

`Child1` Component:

```
async function createRef(refs) {
  await sleep(3000);
  let ref = React.createRef();
  refs.push(ref);
  return ref;
}

function Child1({ lst, refs }) {
  return <>{lst.map(item => <div ref={createRef(refs)}>{`This is item number ${item}`}</div>)}</>;
}
```

`Child2` Component:

```
function Child2({ refs }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    // wait for refs[0] to be defined
    complexFunction(ref[0]) //this is undefined
  });
  return <></>;
}
```

In `Child2` I'm receiving `refs` array that is controlled by `Child1`, in `Child1`, `refs` is built asynchronously. I want to wait for the refs to be built completely before calling `complexFunction` on `refs[0]`.
The only solution I got now is to pass `complexFunction` to `Child1` and call it from there, but I don't prefer this solution because in my real app it takes a lot of infrastructural changes.
I also can wait for a few hundreds `ms` before calling `complexFunction` but it's also not a preferred solution.
I tried to changed `refs` to a `state variable`, `set` it in `Child1` and check if it's defined in `Child2` before calling `complexFunction`, but it triggered infinite loop of setState/renders.

Comment: Why not just lift this logic to the parent?

Comment: @LelandB How do you suggest to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in `<Child2/>` should be moved into the parent since the parent is responsible for orchestrating the children.

Adding something like this to the parent should be helpful.

```
  //you should track async functions with a loading flag
  //it really helps with debugging and have a clean UI
  //The UI is likely odd looking or broken while
  //complexFunction runs.
  const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [refList,setRefList] = useState([]);
  const addRefToList = ref => {
    complexFunction(ref);
    const newRefList = [...refList, ref]
    setRefList(newRefList);
    if (newRefList.length === lst.length) {
      complexFunction(newRefList[0]);
    }
  }

  return <>
   {loading && <LoadingIcon/> }
  ...
  <Child1 addRefToList={addRefToList} .../>
  ...
  </>
```

And make this change to

```
const Child1 = props => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    props.addRefToList(ref);
  });
  return <div ref={ref}>{`This is item number ${props.item}`}</div>
}
```

Comment: I have two notes on this, first, `setRefList(newRefList);` may cause infinite re-render, because in each time it's called, Child1 will be called again, and it will call `setRefList(newRefList);` again.
Second thing: as I learned, it's always not preferred to not setState while rendering as it will cause the issue I mentioned. what do you say?

Comment: I fixed the code in <Child1/>. These things are true, but it is better to stay within the render->re-render loop than to circumvent how react works. In a real application, this can be optimized with React.memo. I am assuming that you don't have options in re-structuring this code in a bigger way.

Comment: It worked well for me, just need to add empty array condition to useEffect in Child1 to prevent infinite re-render. Thanks!